# Moment of inertia of a non uniform rod

Tags: rotation

How to calculate moment of inertia of a non uniform rod about its geometrical center (linear mass density=kx, where k is some constant)?

Comment: Does x range from $0$ to some constant $L$?

Answer (score 3):

The moment of inertia for an object is defined as

$$ I = \int r^2 dm. $$

You can substitute $dm = \rho dV$, where $\rho(x) = kx$, and integrate over your cylinder. I have not provided the full solution because this is a very 'homework-and-exercises'-like problem.